# specify the sort order in "copy /b *.dat foo" in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, sorting

Normally, when I do a `copy /b *.data foo` in Windows cmd, the `*.data` files are catenated in the sorted order into the destination file `foo`. This matches my desired behavior.

However, I just met a curious directory in which this `copy /b` command will copy the files out of order. The order is not exactly random, but second last file in the sorted order will go first, followed by the remaining files in sorted order.

Is there a way to overcome this strange sorting behavior? More generally, what if I want to copy the files, say, in the reverse order?

Comment: What's the name of odd file?

Comment: @Joel The filenames are just nnnnnnnn.data where n is a digit and the numbers are consecutive counting from 1. The odd file is always the second last file in the sorted order. Say if I have 5 files, 00000004.data will come out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will concatenate the files ([even the ones with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487491/how-to-handle-space-of-filename-in-batch-for-loop)) in reverse order:

```
C:\> for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /a-d /o-n /b c:\some_dir\*') do @type %i >> c:\another_dir\dest.dat
```

If there are only a few files, you can list them explicitly:

```
C:\> copy /b c.dat+a.dat+b.dat dest.dat
```

Something like this might work in some situations:

```
C:\> copy /b file*.dat+foo.dat+bar*.dat dest.dat
```

Comment: I must learn to type faster! What Dennis said. Although type (or more) will only do an ASCII copy and copy /b is binary.

Comment: @Rhys: I just tested `type` with binary files and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. I was also suspicious on typing a binary file but apparently it works as expected on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Great. I stand corrected.

Comment: Note that `%` needs to be escaped as `%%` in a `.bat` file.