# Command Line Concat MP3 in ascending order of file name - windows

Tags: command-line, audio, mp3

I am using a simple command for windows in a .bat file to concat all files in folder into one mp3. The files are named 1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, 4.mp3 ect.

It merges them into one file fine but seems to be random order, I am wondering if there is something I can add to the command to concat them by name with lowest number first to highest number (ascending order). Also keeping in mind that numbers are in the 100's so command shouldn't do 1, 2, 20, 200 but 1, 2, 3, 4 ect

Command to concat all mp3s in folder into one mp3:

```
copy /b *.mp3 new.mp3
```

Comment: same folder but it could be different

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/217394/specify-the-sort-order-in-copy-b-dat-foo-in-windows-cmd